Eclipse Generic Text Editor Keeps Updating Outline and Really Slow
I use the generic text editor for javascript editing. I would have hundreds of javascript files and whenever I am editing in those files and only those files, the experience is excruciating. The outline will update after each character is typed or deleted creating a pause of 3 or 4 seconds, on each and every typed character.
If I could turn off the outline I would, even though it is a useful tool.
Does anybody know how to either

Turn off the outline
Stop the outline updating
Know a better js editor to use in Eclipse (the old JDT tools were better but it is a very laborious process to downgrade to them each time I update Eclipse)

At the moment I am using VSCode to edit my js files and Eclipse for everything else.
Update
I'm using these versions
Eclipse Version: 2024-09 (4.33.0)
Build id: 20240905-0614
Wild Web Developer Version 1.3.7.202408270415
Further Update
Thanks howgler for your suggestions.
In reference to closing the outline by clicking the X in the right. I do not have that option 
There is not an option in the menu either. (As an aside I find the fact I do not have a collapse all a bit annoying but have lived with that for a long time). I can detach the outline but that just means the delay due to updating is just shown in the detached view.
Futher Update 2
If I detach the outline view I then see an X to close the view completely. This causes me further issues with other editor windows such as my Java window. The view if closed is closed for everything using that persepctive. I suppose I can change persective depending on the code I'm using, but really I shouldn't have to.
I updated to Wild Web Developer 1.3.9 and it made no difference.
But, after detaching the outline view, closing it and then reattaching it (which I found by trial and error), my outline no longer updates when I type. I have no idea why. It seems detaching, closing, opening and reattaching somehow fixed it. I suspect I did somethig else in my attempt to reattach the view but for the life of me I cannot tell you what.

Just closing the outline view should be enough I guess

Is your Eclipse and the contained Eclipse Wild Web Developer plugin up to date? Please tell both versions.

I've updated the question to include the versions of Eclipse and Wild Web Developer. Fair enouigh comment and I should have included them initially. In response to the suggetion of closing the outline view, that might be enough, but how do you close that view only, so I can test that.

Views are closed in the same way than editors: hitting the X right to the icon and the label Outline. Does the problem also occur with the Minimap (Window > Show View > Other...: General > Minimap) instead of the Outline view?

The current Wild Wev Developer version is 1.3.9: in Help > Install New Software... work with https://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/releases/latest/.

I've further updated the post in reference to closing the Outline view

The missing X is strange. The X is shown for me in all built-in light and dark themes. Have you ever installed a plugin from Genuitec (which patches Eclipse via loadtime weaving, can causing such issues and slow down Eclipse; the vendor of this plugin tries to cheat the open source license of Eclipse by doing so)? Can you close the view via right-clicking on the tab on the word "Outline"? Did you try Wild Web Developer 1.3.9?
